# group by count sql

Tags: sql, oracle, metabase

I have a script

```
SELECT  customer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM devices 
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY 2 desc;
```

and the result is

```
customer_id      count
1234              8
4567              7
8910              7
1112              7
1314              5
1516              5
```

but what I expect is

```
devices      customer
8              1
7              3
5              2
```

Is there any way without using a new table?

Answer (score 2):

Use your current query as a source for another:

```
with temp as
  -- this is your current query
  (select customer_id, 
          count(*) cnt
   from devices
   group by customer_id
  )
select cnt as devices, 
       count(*) as customer
from temp
group by cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual use of count(*) is to find out many rows have been aggregated by group function. Want you ant to do is aggregate your result in a second select, and ask for count(*) a second time to get result you've described.

Comment: I've tried
```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(1)
FROM
(
    SELECT  customer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM devices 
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY 2 desc; 

) devices
GROUP BY customer_id
```
it it doesn't work